# Python count tuples occurence in list

Tags: python, counter, n-gram

Is there a way to count how many times each tuple occurs in this list of tokens?

I have tried the `count` method but it does not work.

This is the list:

```
['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'today', 'are', 'you', 'okay']
```

These are the tuples based on the list:

```
('hello', 'how')
('how', 'are')
('are','you')
('you', 'doing')
('doing', 'today')
('today', 'are')
('you', 'okay')
```

I would like the result to be something like this

```
('hello', 'how')1
('how', 'are')1
('are','you')2
('you', 'doing')1
('doing', 'today')1
('today', 'are')1
('you', 'okay')1
```

Comment: What about using a `Counter`?

Comment: Do the tokens have to be next to each other in the list to match a tuple?

Comment: @chbchb55: that's more or less the idea of an *n*-gram.

Comment: Thanks! I'm quite new to this, but if I want to use the n-grams as a vocabulary where each is listed once and then check how many times they each occur in many different lists is there also a way of doing so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily use a `Counter` for that. A generic function to count *n*-grams is the following:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import islice

def count_ngrams(iterable,n=2):
    return Counter(zip(*[islice(iterable,i,None) for i in range(n)]))
```

This generates:

```
>>> count_ngrams(['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'today', 'are', 'you', 'okay'],2)
Counter({('are', 'you'): 2, ('doing', 'today'): 1, ('you', 'doing'): 1, ('you', 'okay'): 1, ('today', 'are'): 1, ('how', 'are'): 1, ('hello', 'how'): 1})
>>> count_ngrams(['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'today', 'are', 'you', 'okay'],3)
Counter({('are', 'you', 'okay'): 1, ('you', 'doing', 'today'): 1, ('are', 'you', 'doing'): 1, ('today', 'are', 'you'): 1, ('how', 'are', 'you'): 1, ('doing', 'today', 'are'): 1, ('hello', 'how', 'are'): 1})
>>> count_ngrams(['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'today', 'are', 'you', 'okay'],4)
Counter({('doing', 'today', 'are', 'you'): 1, ('today', 'are', 'you', 'okay'): 1, ('are', 'you', 'doing', 'today'): 1, ('how', 'are', 'you', 'doing'): 1, ('you', 'doing', 'today', 'are'): 1, ('hello', 'how', 'are', 'you'): 1})
```

Answer (score 6):

This solution requires a third-party module ([`iteration_utilities.Iterable`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/Iterable.html)) but should do what you want:

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import Iterable

>>> l = ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'today', 'are', 'you', 'okay']

>>> Iterable(l).successive(2).as_counter()
Counter({('are', 'you'): 2,
         ('doing', 'today'): 1,
         ('hello', 'how'): 1,
         ('how', 'are'): 1,
         ('today', 'are'): 1,
         ('you', 'doing'): 1,
         ('you', 'okay'): 1})
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I should do if I want to use the n-grams as a vocabulary, and then check this vocabulary against many lists?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Maybe that could warrant another question where you can explain more clearly what you need.